# How to get listoffigures as a horizontal list?

Tags: table-of-contents

Is there a way to have `\listoffigures` displayed as a horizontal list of figure number, caption and page number divided by `|`?

> Fig. 1: Caption of Figure 1 | 2; Fig. 2: Caption of Figure 2 | 4; Fig. 3: Caption of Figure 3 | 82; Fig. 4: Caption of Figure 4 | 282

And is there also a way to suppress the page numbers? e.g.

> Fig. 1: Caption of Figure 1; Fig. 2: Caption of Figure 2 Fig. 3: Caption of Figure 3; Fig. 4: Caption of Figure 4

As MWE I provide

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{
\renewcommand*\l@figure{\@dottedtocline{1}{2.4cm}{.5cm}}
\renewcommand{\@dotsep}{10000}
}
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\bfseries\arabic{figure}}

\begin{document}

    \captionof{figure}{example-image-a}
    \captionof{figure}{example-image-b}
    \captionof{figure}{example-image-c}

\listoffigures
\end{document}
```

Comment: The tricky bit is that the first argument of \l@figure includes the \numberline macro.  See the aux or lof files.

Comment: Have you considered using multicols instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need a custom version of `\numberline`:

```
\def\numberline#1#2{%
  \lofsep\space{\let\bfseries\relax Fig. #1: #2}
}
```

`\lofsep` will be the vertical line and `\let\bfseries\relax` because by default `\bfseries` gets written into the `.lof` file. At last you need to say `\let\l@figure\@firstoftwo`, so the page number simply is forgotten.

[image: output]

### Complete Code

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\let\l@figure\@firstoftwo
\let\ltx@numberline\numberline
\preto\listoffigures{
  \def\numberline#1#2{%
    \lofsep\space{\let\bfseries\relax Fig. #1: #2}
  }
  \def\lofsep{\def\lofsep{\(\mid\)}}
}
\appto\listoffigures{\let\numberline\ltx@numberline}
\makeatother

\renewcommand*\thefigure{\bfseries\arabic{figure}}

\begin{document}
\captionof{figure}{example-image-a}
\captionof{figure}{example-image-b}
\captionof{figure}{example-image-c}
\listoffigures
\end{document}
```

Comment: Excellent! Works like a charm!